# How to get the first column of a list without transforming it in a dataframe in Python?

Tags: python, list

I have a list `A` that is like a `2D` array, so

```
A[0]= ('Tom', 89.0196078431373, 'Jim', None)
```

I want to get each column separately. This is what I am doing:

```
L = list()
df1 = pd.DataFrame(A)
L.append(A.ix[:,2], A.ix[:,1], A.ix[:,3])
```

I am wondering if there is a similar way without transforming it in a `dataframe`

Comment: 4D? A[0] would not look like `('Tom', 89.0196078431373, 'Jim', None)` if the list was 4D. Can you maybe provide your actual list `A`. Do you mean that you have `4` entries in your list in a manner of `somename,number,name,None`?

Comment: For instance `A[0][2]='Jim'` and `len(A) = 2853` so `A` has `2853x4` entries

Answer (score 1):

If you have a `2D` array you can store the column `i` into a list like this:

```
l = [row[i] for row in A]
```